# How do I make a particular option disappear from a combobox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a combobox in my page with a wide selection of options. When a user selects an option and clicks a buttom, the options dissapear from the table under it.

But you see, I can't make the option dissapear IN the combobox. I tried using .hide() but the option is still there, if you use your arrows you can still find it. Here's what I got so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $("#combo").load("/intl/servlet/apps.gpa.HTMLGPA?p1=all_dropdown",function(){
        $("#button").html("<input type=\"button\" value=\"Filter\">");

    });
    $("#bigTable ").load("/intl/servlet/apps.gpa.HTMLGPA?p1=bigTable");
    $("#button").click(function(){
        var currentSelection = $("#select").val();
        $("#bigTable table tbody tr").each(function( index) {
            var str = $(this).text().trim();    
            if(str.substring(0, 4).trim()==currentSelection ){
                $(this).hide()
            }   
        })
        $("#combo select option").each(function( index) {                   
            if($(this).val()==currentSelection ){
                $(this).hide()
            }   
        })
    });
});
```

As you can see, the last piece of code is doing the hiding for the combo box:

```
$("#combo select option").each(function( index) {                   
            if($(this).val()==currentSelection ){
                $(this).hide()
            }   
        })
```

Is there anyway I can make the option completly dissapear and NOT be accessed by the keyboard?

Comment: ...and your combobox?

Comment: it will be good if you create a fiddle for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use 
$("#combo select option").each(function( index) {                   
            if($(this).val()==currentSelection ){
                $(this).remove()
            }   
        })
```

Comment: That was rather obvious. Thank you.